# Why does my "exit" command not exit my Bash script?

Tags: bash

I have this Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
function doSomething() {
    callee
    echo "It should not go to here!"
}

function callee() {
    ( echo "before" ) && (echo "This is callee" && exit 1 )                                                                                   
    echo "why I can see this?"
}


doSomething
```

and this is the result:

```
+ set -x
+ doSomething
+ callee
+ echo before
before
+ echo 'This is callee'
This is callee
+ exit 1
+ echo 'why I can see this?'
why I can see this?
+ echo 'It should not go to here!'
It should not go to here!
```

I see the command `exit`, but it doesn't exit the script – why doesn't `exit` work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling `exit` from inside a subshell, so that's the shell that is exiting. Try this instead:

```
function callee() {
    ( echo "before" ) && { echo "This is callee" && exit 1; }                                                                                   
    echo "why I can see this?"
}
```

This, however, will exit from whatever shell called `callee`. You may want to use `return` instead of `exit` to return from the function.

Answer (score 3):

When you run a command in `()` you're spawning a subshell. So when you call `exit` within that subshell, you're just exiting it, and not your top level script.

Answer (score 2):

Because round paredenthesis creates a new nested shell, which is exited with exit.