# exit command doesn't work in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I would like my script ends working if a specific file is not found. Therefore I write the following:

```
[ -f "$DAEMON" ] || (echo "File $DAEMON not found" && exit 0)
```

But it doesn't work properly. If the file doesn't exist, my script outputs this error message and continues working.

I tried

```
[ -f "$DAEMON" ] || { echo "File $DAEMON not found" && exit 0 }
```

(as it is suggested here [exit doesn't work in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266057/exit-doesnt-work-in-bash) ), but I got syntax error (unexpected end of file).

`[ -f "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0` works well but `[ -f "$DAEMON" ] || (exit 0)`
 doesn't.

How can I output error message and stop script executing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your compound command (the `{ ... }` construct) requires the semi-colon before the closing brace - it isn't optional! So this will work:

```
[ -f "$DAEMON" ] || { echo "File $DAEMON not found" && exit 0; }
```

Comment: semicolon or the closing brace could be in the new line.

Answer (score 4):

I think you'll probably find that, in `someErrorProgram || (exit 0)`, the `exit 0` is being run in a *sub-shell* due to the parentheses. That means the `exit` will exit from the sub-shell rather than the shell you think it's running in.

But, unless you're absolutely *desperate* to keep it on one line, I'd just use:

```
if [[ ! -f "$DAEMON" ]] ; then
    echo "File $DAEMON not found"
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Nicer solution than mine is :D

Comment: Yes, I know about if statement, but for me it is interesting how to do it on one line.

Answer (score 4):

In such scenarios I using my `errecho` function, like

```
errecho() { echo "$@" >&2; return 1; }
```

the return 1 allows me chain the error condition, e.g. like

```
[[ -f file ]] || errecho "file doesnt exists" || exit 1
```

and it is useful for deeper functions too like

```
action() {

     [[ some cond ]] || errecho "errmsg" || return 1
}

do_something() {
    action "$1" "$3" || errecho "action failed with $3" || return 1
}

#main
do_something || errecho "total fail " || exit 1
```

Answer (score 3):

use if statement:

```
if [ ! -f "$DAEMON" ]
then
  echo "File $DAEMON not found"
  exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Yes, I know about if statement, but for me it is interesting how to do it on one line.

Comment: Your solution lacks not operator (!) before -f

Answer (score 1):

You can use this if you want a single line solution and it works

```
[[ -f "filename" ]] || { echo "file doesnt exists" && exit ;}

echo "bye"
```

I didn't got the bye in console if the file not.

Comment: @jm666 : Oh yes. My idea was to stop the script but anyway I just modified the script to make it work even it found the file.I found the semicolon is missing and did that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop and if statement. With the echo you can check until which point the script went. In the current case the script breaks if it encounters Daemon or C and so only echos A and B.

```
for i in A B Daemon C; do

if 
[ $i == Daemon ] || 
[ $i == C ]

then
    break
fi

echo "$i"

done
```